# Why do I keep needing to rebuild solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm new to Visual Studio, so I haven't gotten used to things yet. I've been using it for weeks with no problem, but today I've noticed that I have to click rebuild solution every time I make any changes to my code, otherwise it'll run an old version of the code. Is this a common thing? I've never had to do it until today, then all of a sudden I have to do it every time.

Comment: Depends on what type of project(s) you are building. Provide more information.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a beginner, so I'm not sure what information to provide. I'm building a simple character based checkers game. I'm using 3 cpp files and 1 header file

Comment: So you are building a C++ project. Update your question and add C++ as as a tag (See `Edit Tags` on your question). For C++ is different from C#/F# and those build differently.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has multiple stages, the compile stage to the link stage. If code changes, VS has to build (compile) and then link those changes into the app. If a library changes, then VS needs to link in the library changes.

If you are having to rebuild everytime, then VS is detecting some type of change to either a C++ file or a linked in library. Finding what is changing will tell you why you have to rebuild to keep the exe (app) current.

---

On a side note, if you are debugging and the debugger seems to step into comments/places it shouldn't be...then your code is in need of being (re)-compiled and linked. For the pdb (debug) files are out of sync with the textual code files that were changed and that is why the debugger is behaving as such.